Every countable subset is complete then M is complete.
Suppose every countable, closed subset of $M$ is complete. We must show $M$ is complete.
Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $M$.
Define $E = \{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$, a countable subset of $M$.
If $cl(E) = E$, then $E$ is closed and, by hypothesis, complete.
If $cl(E) \neq E$, then $\exists x \in cl(E) \setminus E$.
$x$ is a limit point of $E$, so $\exists$ subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to $x$.
Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, the entire sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.
Therefore, $M$ is complete.
If there are any mistake let me know

I assume you are working in a metric space since you are characterizing the closure with limits of sequences.
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space s.t. every countable subset is complete. We want to show that in fact $X$ is complete. 
Let $\left(x_n\right)_n \subseteq X$ be a Cauchy sequence and consider $A = \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then   $\left(x_n\right)_n$ is Cauchy in $A$.
We know that $A$ is complete so that $\left(x_n\right)_n$ converges in $A\subseteq X$. Thus it also converges in $X$ which shows completeness of $X$.
Edit: if we assume every closed, countable subset is complete we can proceed as follows:
First we imitate the above, and consider the set $\overline{A}$. Since we are in a metric space it is obtained by adding all limit points of $A$, so limit points of subsequences of  $\left(x_n\right)_n$. Now, if a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges, the entire sequence converges. Thus by uniqueness of limits in metric spaces, $\overline{A}$ is obtained from $A$ by adding to it at most one point.
Hence, $\overline{A}$ is closed and countable so complete.
We infer, as before, that $\left(x_n\right)_n$ must converge in $\overline{A} \subseteq X$, showing completeness of $X$.

But A have to closed otherwise we have other case.

Q title says "every countable subset" but Q body says "every closed countable subset".

See the edit for closed and countable sets are complete
